# Accessing PCI Device Memory

Tags: c#, pointers, resources

I am trying to write a program that uses dual ported RAM. I have a made a pointer to the memory address listed in the resources for the device in device manager. But every time I try to read from it, I get an Access Violation, what I am doing wrong? According to the device manufacturer, an offset of 0x0800 is open to read and write.

[image: Device Memory Range]

```
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(0xF7E00000);

float value = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr, 0x0800);
MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

Comment: 1) 0xF7E00000 is mapped in your process address space. 2) You can't read/write outside your process (in general). 3) `in` and `out` instructions aren't available in User Mode. 4) You may p/invoke `DeviceIoControl` (and related stuff) using device name (not its I/O addresses).

Comment: Have you checked your memory address space to confirm if it's virtual or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a physical address, you need a device driver.  You can't create a device driver with .NET.  If the device comes with a driver, it probably has an API you can call.

If you really need to write a driver, I'd recommend downloading the DDK from Microsoft, and learning C and kernel-mode programming.  This is not a simple task.